# angular2 unset outlets with routerLink

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

my template looks like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="rightpanel"></router-outlet>
```

let's say my url is:

```
/#/page1(rightpanel:panel)
```

I want to switch to page2 and remove the auxiliary outlet using the routerLink directive. I have tried the following ways:

```
[routerLink]="['/page2', {outlets: {rightpanel: null}}
[routerLink]="['/page2', {outlets: {}}
```

In both cases, the page is switched to page2, but the `rightpanel` is still active. The only way I can solve is by putting the following code in the constructor of page2:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {rightpanel: null}}]);
```

which is not a good solution for many reasons.

Using angular 2.4.3, router 3.4.3

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the primary outlet rather than just the URL.  Personally to me this seems like very odd behaviour, but you can make it work by doing this:

```
[routerLink]="[{outlets: { primary: 'page2', rightpanel: null }}]"
```

According to the documentation, `primary` is the name of the unnamed outlet.